# React-native ComponentDidMount not firing

Tags: reactjs, expo

i tried to update the sound array which i imported from other component every time it is changed. But however, it only fire componentDidMount() only once and it won't run again. Down below is my code on the problem:

```
//sound array from another component
import { soundArray } from "./CreateRecord";

export default class RecordingList extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.currentSoundArray = [];
  }

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.currentSoundArray);
    this.getCurrentArray();
  }

getCurrentArray() {
    this.currentSoundArray = soundArray;
  }

render(){
...
}
```

currently when i view the component, the componentDidMound will run once and console the sound array. At first, the sound array is empty:

```
[]
```

However, after i put value in the sound array and comeback to view the component, it wont print the console and it won't update the value of this.currentSoundArray

My expected result should be the currentSoundArray will be changed and  print to the console every time the soundArray has been changed in another component. for example:

```
[]

[1,2]

[1,2,4]
```

Comment: Can you post expo snack example for your problem

Comment: Hi, my real code is too long to put on snack

Comment: Have you tried ComponentWillMount() ?

Comment: Yes I did, i also tried ComponentDidUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

It runs only once.

Comment: Hi is there a way to update the currentSoundArray each time the soundArray is changed in other component?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is access `currentSoundArray` value when it is updated from another component, now that you will not be able to do traditionally.

Also `componentDidMount` fires only once when the component is first initialized and rendered.

### Solution 1

A better way of doing this is using something like [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to manage your application state, this way you would be able to access the states from any component throughout your application.

I have just finished setting up a boiler plate template for this exact thing, if you would like to check it out its on [Github](https://github.com/AbdeenM/react-native-expo-kit) :)

### Solution 2

If you are not interested in Redux then i would suggest you use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this, it will solve your issue as well. you can check out many examples online for example [this](https://itnext.io/understanding-the-react-context-api-through-building-a-shared-snackbar-for-in-app-notifications-6c199446b80c) uses context to share a snackbar across components.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Hi Abdeen, thanks for your help. I just tried the react context and currently it has to be functions so i have to change every thing to function while i'm operating with class at the moment -> it will be a mess if i change all those code. And for redux. does it need to have an action to change the data? such as press a button etc?